How I can remove the white borders around windows on Ubuntu 24.04?
I have tried many themes but the white borders around windows are not removed even when I disable installed extensions. See the following screenshots:


How I can fix this issue?

You most likely have enabled the High Contrast accessibility setting which enhances the contrast of items by using darker borders around them when using a light theme and lighter borders when using a dark theme.
You can follow these steps to disable the setting:

Open Settings.

Go to Accessibility → Seeing.

Disable High Contrast.




Thanks a lot, it's worked

@HarshDevPathak You're welcome!
